# Dojo GridX inside-column filter plugin?

Tags: filter, dojo, dojo.gridx

Does the GridX have the functionality of inside-column filtering such as PrimeFaces DataTable: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf?

I couldn't find an example for it, or extension plugin doing this, but I'm not sure what is the standard name for column-wide filtering placed in column header...

A filtering isn't hard to implement, but the most tricky part is placing a component within header. I couldn't find an example for it too. This is somethign that should be possible with non-hacking way as well, but how to do that?